# Spring Security Saml SSO integration not working and receiving the following InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I'm currently working on an application with AngularJS, Spring MVC, Spring Security and SAML 2.0 Extension. I’m new to Spring Security SAML and I’ve ran into multiple issues and this is the latest one.

InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a1f4a0e24c8a49a99f1h9df73e95c2

All of my saml configuration files are available here 
https://github.com/MatthewLangford/samlConfig/tree/master

I have followed the saml example implementation here
https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

I have been following the AngularJS with Spring Security blog here
jasha.eu/blogposts/2015/10/saml-authentication-angularjs-spring-security.html

I’ve searched the internet for the solution to this and it seems like a common problem, and as per the spring security saml documentation this issue can be solved by setting the storageFactory property to the SAMLContextProviderImpl like so

```
     @Bean
     public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() {
           SAMLContextProviderImpl samlContextProviderImpl = new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
           samlContextProviderImpl.setStorageFactory(emptyStorageFactory());
           return samlContextProviderImpl;
     }

     @Bean
     public EmptyStorageFactory emptyStorageFactory() {
         return new EmptyStorageFactory();
     }
```

But still I am getting the same error.

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE, Spring Security 4.2.3.RELEASE, spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.2.RELEASE, AngularJS 1.5.8

I am loading the sp and idp metadata locally to the spring saml config, but the idp is a remote entity and sp is local entity.
It is an angularjs based web application and application flow is supposed to be I hit the url that takes me to an insecure page with a login link, after I hit the login link I am sending a request to the sso controller that does a logical check on whether I am a authenticated user or not, if not I am supposed to be redirected to the sso for authentication.

Please provide your valuable input to help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This typically means that request with SAMLResponse (the one that is sent back to sp after authentication) does not have same http session that was used to send request to idp. Open dev tools in your browser and verify session id cookies. You may also have something messed up in configuration because if your application was indeed using _EmptyStorageFactory_ you would not get that exception. ESF completely disables that check.

Comment: Thank you for the response,  I have been over my saml config many times and I couldn't figure out the issue. can you please have a look at my saml config under this github repo https://github.com/MatthewLangford/samlConfig/tree/master

Comment: Im afraid it is to complex, at least for me, to analyze this without working application.

Comment: If it helps root out the problem this is what comes up in the logs when I hit the url that takes me to the sso   <saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https ://myapp.com/saml/SSO/alias/myapp.com" Destination="https ://idp/affwebservices/public/saml2sso" ForceAuthn="false" ID="a2gebdfc58h80ag728d6279da4ib834" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2017-08-08T22:53:55.745Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">

Comment: <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> http ://myapp.com</saml2:Issuer><saml2p:Scoping ProxyCount="2"/></saml2p:AuthnRequest>